# Is there any alternative method to dequeueReusableCell in SwiftUI, similar to UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui, uikit

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI project and encountered a scenario where I need to achieve something similar to the dequeueReusableCell method in UIKit. In UIKit, I would typically reuse cells to optimize memory usage in a UITableView or UICollectionView.

Is there an equivalent or alternative method in SwiftUI for reusing views or components in a similar manner? I've searched the documentation and forums but haven't found a clear solution yet.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
// Example in UIKit
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
// Do something with the cell...

// What would be the equivalent in SwiftUI?
// Is there a mechanism for reusing views efficiently?
```

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: SwiftUI views are structs and cannot be reused. If you are using a List or LazyGrid, the reuse of underlying UICollectionViewCells is managed for you. Why do you think you need to reuse views?

Comment: SwiftUI is all about the data, it will create/update/remove UIViews automatically and it does do cell reuse, in case of List it uses UICollectionView, you can use the view debugger to verify this and Instruments to check the number of instances. If your list is slow then try breaking it up into more child View types.

Comment: "encountered a scenario where I need to achieve something similar to the dequeueReusableCell method in UIKit" Are you *sure*? Can you tell more about the scenario? You should not need to handle the reuse of cells in SwiftUI.

Comment: In SwiftUI, there isn't a direct equivalent to dequeueReusableCell as it exists in UIKit for managing reusable cells in table views or collection views. However, SwiftUI provides a more declarative approach to building user interfaces, and it handles view reuse and recycling implicitly.

In SwiftUI, you typically use List or ForEach to create a dynamic list of views, and SwiftUI manages the view hierarchy and reuse behind the scenes. Here's an example of how you might create a list of dynamic views in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1):

Cell dequeueing happens automatically for any views of the same type inside SwiftUI's [List](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list) and [Grid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid) which are equivalent to UIKit's `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` respectively

```
List(arr,id:\.self) { row in
   DetailListCell(.....  <<< Will be dequeued
```

Answer (score 1):

TableView equivalent to SwiftUI is a `List`. You will also have `ForEach` within a List to indicate a kind of `cell`. Simply place any `View` inside the ForEach content block, it's a "cell" appearance:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var list = Array(0...100)

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(list, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("List here")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]